# Extract specific string using JavaScript using regex

Tags: javascript

I tried with this

```
var regex =  /.*<\s+(.*)\s+>.*/g;
```

but it is not working

Sample string:

```
your call average is <result.x> OK. <result.y> <result.b>
```

I want all strings between `<` and `>` using regex

Thanks in advance,

Comment: use `myStr.match(/<(.*?)>/g);`

Comment: No it is also not working.if possible can u please write completely like a function

Comment: added code snippet also. have a look.

Answer (score 1):

use below regex for extract the result.

`var regex = /<(.*?)>/g;`

```js
var myStr = 'your call average is <result.x> OK. <result.y> <result.b>';

var arr = [];
var regex = /<([^>]+)>/g;
var match;

while( match = regex.exec( myStr ) ) {
    arr.push( match[1] );
}


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: The OP wants string b/w the `<>` not with `<>`

Comment: Thanks check code again i updated for desire results.

Comment: @PraveenR If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like `/\<([^<>]*)\>\/g`. You can find explanation at https://regex101.com/r/DOR7C7/1. It will match all the characters except `<` or `>` inside `<..>` and capture the results.

**JavaScript Code**

```js
let str = `your call average is <result.x> OK. <result.y> <result.b>`;
let re = /\<([^<>]*)\>/g;

let res = re.exec(str);
let results = [];
while(res){
    results.push(res[1]);
    res = re.exec(str);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/<\s*(.*?)\s*>/g
```

Group 1 is the string you want.    [Online Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Ce2ooa/1)

```js
const regex = /<\s*(.*?)\s*>/gm;
const str = `your call average is <result.x> OK. <result.y> <result.b>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    
    console.log(m[1])
}
```

Note that you can optionally enable the `s` option to match `<>` that spans multiple lines.

Explanation:

The `.*` at the start and end of your regex is not needed because you are not trying to match anything outside of the `<>`. This is why your regex should start with `<` and ends with `>`. After matching some whitespaces, you start to capture the things inside the `<>` with `(.*?)`. Note that I used a lazy quantifier here. This is so that it stops matching as soon as it sees a `>`. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = "your call average is <result.x> OK. <result.y> <result.b>".split('>')
var result = []
d.forEach(function(te) {
  if (!te.trim()) return
  var t = te.split('<').pop()
  if (!t.trim()) return
  result.push(t)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Without Regular Eaxpression You can do.if you are going by Regular Expression you need to match manything.so go by normal split